# Vectorising np.where function in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have a pandas dataframe, df. The column 'group_ids' consists of numpy arrays (for each row). I am trying to create a new column, that will find the number of occurrences of the group_ids, within the numpy array 'id_list'.

The following code works, although it is slow for large datasets:

```
df['sum_binary'] = ''
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    df['sum_binary'][i] = sum(np.where(np.in1d(df['group_ids'][i], id_list),1,0))
```

How could I vectorise this? I have tried using pandas.where, without any success, for example:

```
df['1'] = 1
df['sum_binary'] = (df['1']).where(np.in1d(df['group_ids'], id_list),0)
```

Comment: Can you share a minimal example and expected output?

Comment: Also why are you using sum? You're iterating row-wise, the result will be either 1 or 0. Also the assignment won't work since you're indexing wrong. You should be using `loc`

Comment: I think you just want `df['group_ids'].isin(id_list).astype(int)`...

Comment: @yatu - "SystemError: <built-in method view of numpy.ndarray object at 0x7f96c5acb2b0> returned a result with an error set." The column group_ids consists of numpy arrays.

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible example if you want to get any help. Otherwise there's not much we can do